# An exception is getting thrown when trying to show progressbar

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, prism, dispatcher

I have a requirement to show a progress bar in my WPF application when I navigate from one view to another view. I've a service to show and close the progress bar. My code to show the progress bar goes like below. And it's showing perfectly fine.

```
public void ShowProgressBar<T>() where T : Window
        {
            var thread = new Thread(
                new ThreadStart(
                    delegate ()
                    {
                        _progressWindow = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                        _progressWindow .Show();
                        _currentDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                        Dispatcher.Run();                        
                    }
                ));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
```

After the progress bar is being shown, I'm trying to navigate to another view using viewManagementService wherein it removed existing view from the region if any and adds the new view and Since I know the last method that gets hit, I'm trying to close my progress bar there withe same service class being injected into its constructor and my closing logic goes like this.

```
public void CloseProgressBar()
        {
            if (_progressWindow != null && _currentDispatcher != null)
            {
                //Close the window and shutdown the dispatcher.
                _currentDispatcher.Invoke(() => CloseWindow());
            }
            else if(_progressWindow != null && _currentDispatcher == null)
            {
                _progressWindow.Close();
            }            
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// CloseWindow
        /// </summary>
        private void CloseWindow()
        {
            _progressWindow.Close();
            _currentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        }
```

But, while trying to do this, it's sometimes saying that the task is already cancelled or it's saying that the task is being owned by a different thread. I couldn't figure out whether the problem is with my code or the way I'm doing?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'd try implementing the progress bar as a singleton (without any dispatchers in it) and call it from the views using their own dispatchers. This approach works for me at least.

Comment: Can you please attach a sample of code for reference on how to call it from the views using their own dispatchers? That would surely help me.

Comment: I don't have any code at hand right now, I can give you some clues. Create a dialog containing your progress bar. Implement it as a singleton pattern (e.g. public static MyProgressDialog Instance returning always the only one instance of the progress bar). Add Show and Close static methods that do what they are supposed to do. If you need progress bar advancement, implement public static AdvanceTo(double percent) method that will set the progress bar to the desired percentage. It may be necessary to use the dispatcher inside this method. This way you'll always have access to your progress bar